# How to keep tab when pushing a new page?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

When I push a new tab like this in my controller:

`this.nav.push(EditPage);`

the tab disappears. How can I keep the tab?

Pic below:

[image]

When the new page comes:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to add the `tabSubPages:false` config in your `ionicBootstrap` like this:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {      
    tabSubPages:false
});
```

By doing that, and because that each tab has its own history stack, and `NavController` instances injected into children `@Components` of each tab will be unique to each tab, the new page will be opened inside the current tab.

---

**UPDATE:**

Please notice that with the new release of Ionic [2.0.0-beta.11 (2016-08-05)](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-2016-08-05) that config was renamed to `tabsHideOnSubPages` so it should be:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {      
    tabsHideOnSubPages:false
});
```

> The previous names have been deprecated. They will still work in the
>   current release but will be removed in the future so please update to
>   the new names.

Comment: hey thanks bro, i was doing the same thing at first but without the array arg in the middle. the original comes like this: ionicBoostrap(MyApp), so I add the object with property tabSubPages:false as the second arg.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras, how to hidetabs in sub pages ionic2? tabsHideOnSubPages:true is not working. Where should I add 
  ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [], {      
    tabsHideOnSubPages:false
});

Comment: It's done in the app.module.ts:
`imports: [
  ..,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
   backButtonText: '',
   mode: 'wp',
   // tabSubPages: false
   tabsHideOnSubPages: false
  }),`