# Ionic 2 : navigation - Tab Bar missing after push

Tags: ionic2

i have a bottom tab bar which has 4 tabs(home,about,contact,more) following is the code of tabs page.

Html:

```
<page-more [hidden]="more"></page-more>
```

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab  (ionSelect)="more1()" tabTitle="More" tabIcon="more"></ion-tab>
```

ts:

```
 @Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

    tab1Root: any = HomePage;
    tab2Root: any = AboutPage;
    tab3Root: any = ContactPage;
    tab4Root: any = MorePage;
    more: boolean = true;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

    more1() {
        if (this.more == true) this.more = false; else this.more = true;
    }

    gallery() {
        this.navCtrl.push(GalleryPage);
    }
}
```

And my 'page more' Component html:

```
    <ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar position="bottom">      
        <ion-segment>
            <ion-segment-button title="Gallery" value="all" (click)="gallery()">
                <ion-icon name="images"></ion-icon>
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>    
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

morePage.ts:

```
@Component({
selector: 'page-more',
templateUrl: 'More.html'

})
```

export class MorePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

```
ionViewWillEnter() {

}

gallery() {

    this.navCtrl.push(GalleryPage);
}
```

}

when i click on more on tab bar, page more  will be show on top of the current tab bar .After click event on 'Gallery' it redirects to gallery page it's all good till now ,but my tab bar is missing in Gallery page.

GalleryPage Html:

```
   <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>      
        <ion-title>Gallery</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <div *ngIf="!showImages">
        <ion-list *ngFor="let g of galleryData">
            <ion-card>
                <img src="assets/{{g.eventThumbImage}}" alt="your image" (click)="getEventImages(g.imageeventId)">
                <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-card-title>
                        <a (click)="getEventImages(g.imageeventId)">{{g.photoEventName}}</a>
                    </ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-list>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

GalleryPage ts:

```
@Component({

selector:'gallery-page',

templateUrl: 'gallery.html'

})



export class GalleryPage
 {


 galleryData;

 showImages: boolean;

 eventImagesData: Array<any> = [];

 results: any[];


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private apiService: ApiService) {
    }



       ionViewWillEnter() {

           this.getImages();

       }



       getImages() {

        this.showImages = false;
        this.apiService.getData('GalleryController/CallForImageEvents')
            .subscribe(galleryData => this.galleryData = galleryData);
       }


}
```

So,please tell me where i was going wrong....

Comment: Can you post the `Gallery` page structure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41842309/4826457

Comment: did you put `tabsHideOnSubPages` as false?

Comment: i tried not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tabs disappears ionic 3 after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784051/tabs-disappears-ionic-3-after-push)

Answer (score 0):

Lets explain the problem.

You have a tabs page and it has a container to display the tab selected.
You have components that are in the view of the tabs and have their own navigation.

This here function exists in TabsPage:

```
gallery() {
    this.navCtrl.push(GalleryPage);
}
```

The navCtrl that it is referring to is of TabsPage. So if you push here it will push not in to the view but away from the TabsPage.

Simply all you have to do is **create a more page component and move your gallery function there**.

Comment: i worked with this approach earlier but there is a problem with this approach.i.e, when i was in home page and i click on more it go to more component and displays more html hiding home page, but it should show on home page or any other page which is active.