# Tabs disappears ionic 3 after push

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

My Tabs disappears after using `this.navCtrl.push(NamePage);`

I don't understand, I need use `@ViewChild` or another function?
I have set `tabsHideOnSubPages` on `false` in *app.module.ts*

Example : https://github.com/Nicolas-PL/TestMenu

Files is : `src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts` and `src/pages/test/test.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { TestPage } from '../test/test';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = TestPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  openModal() {
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(TestPage);
    myModal.present();

  }
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="openModal()" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Test.ts (tabs disappears)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage {

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}
  ionViewDidLoad() {}

  openMenu() {
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
}

}
```

I have try  `this.navCtrl.root(HomePage);` but don't works..

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you create a complete, minimal and verifiable example and add the code directly to your question?

Comment: hi ! Done ! Thanks

Comment: Can you put the relevant `code` here too (on your post above)?

Comment: Hello, Done ! Help me please :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to navigate from an `overlay` component (`popover`, `modal`, `alert`, etc) then you must do it like below.

*test.ts*

```
export class TestPage {
    constructor(
      public viewCtrl: ViewController
      public appCtrl: App
    ) {}

    openMenu() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);
    }
  }
```

You can read more about [**it here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)(see under the title `Navigating from an Overlay Component`).

Answer (score 2):

I just found a workaround.

Tab disappear if push() is called from a page that's not in the tab.
So, I call an event

`this.events.publish('gotochat', { item: element });`

Then, I navigate to my root Tab

```
this.nav.setRoot('TabsPage', { index: 1 }, {
        animate: true,
        direction: 'forward'
      });
```

In the land page, I listen to the event and push the desired page.

```
this.events.subscribe('gotochat', (item) => {
  this.navCtrl.push('ItemDetailPage', {
    home: true,
    chat: item.item
  })
})
```